# Проблемы с адаптацией под телефоны

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Адаптировал сайт под все телефоны. Но на всех телефонах  отображается адаптация под iphone 5.Даже когда я удаляю адаптацию под айфон 5 мой телефон (galaxy core prime  разширение 480x800) открывает сайт с разширением 320x568( iphone 5 ).На компе показывает все нормально а на телефоне нет.

[image: Так должно смотрется под 480x800]

[image: Но на телефони адаптация как на айфоне 5]

```css
/* IPHONE 5*/
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and  (max-width:324px) {
 body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 #logo{
  margin-left:0;
 }
 .navbar{
  margin-top:-20px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse, .collapse{
  border:none !important;
  margin-top:10px;
 }
 .header{
  height: 568px;
  background-size: 300%;
 }
 .header-name>.row>.col-lg-6>h1{
  font-size: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:240px;
  margin-left: 30px;
 }
 .header-name{
  margin-top:96px;
 }
 .header-name>.row>.col-lg-6>h5{
  font-size: 19px;
  width:240px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
 }
 .header-iphone>img{
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
 }
} 


/*GALAXY CORE PRIME */ 
@media screen  and(min-width:422px) and (max-width:485px) {
 #logo{
  margin-left:0;
 }
 .navbar{
  margin-top:-20px;
 }
 .nav>li>a{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 110%;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .navbar-collapse, .collapse{
  border:none !important;
  margin-top:10px;
 }
 .header{
  max-height: 800px;
  background-size: 280%;
 }
 .header-name>.row>.col-lg-6>h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  width:300px;
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 .header-name{
  margin-top:96px;
 }
 .header-name>.row>.col-lg-6>h5{
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width:300px;
  margin-top:17px;
 }
 .header-iphone>img{
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>HeyU</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="fonts/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="media-header.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span id="logo">HeyU</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li ><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container header-name">
   <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 container">
     <h1>Simple, safe<br>& beautiful.</h1>

     <h5><span class="header-h5">With <span class="HeyU">HeyU</span>, you'll get fast, simple, secure messaging!</span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="header-iphone col-lg-6 col-xs-6 ">
     <img src="img/iphone-7-silver.png">
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут ты не много путаешь понятия физического разрешения экрана и софтверного (аппаратно-независимого).

К примеру, у iphone 5 физическое разрешение экрана 1136 x 640, но на уровне софта, браузера, шириной экрана будет 320. Аналогично на твоем смартфоне получается.

upd: вот ссылка на хабр https://habrahabr.ru/post/145619/